# Use services instead init method in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I have init() method in my controller which looks like this:

```
class MyController extends GlobalController
{

    private function init()
    {
        $this->setVariables($first = false, $second = true); // this comes from GlobalController
        $this->bill_repository = $this->setRepository('Bill');
        $this->var = .....;
        ....
    }

    ...
}
```

and GlobalController is like this:

```
class GlobalController extends BaseController
{
    //Frequently used variables
    protected $user;
    protected $em;
    protected $expense_repository;

    protected function setVariables($first, $second)
    {
        $this->user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();

        if($first){
            $this->em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        }

        if($second){
            $this->expense_repository = $this->setRepository('Expense');
        }
    }
}
```

How to improve this using services? The understanding I get after reading Symfony's documentation is that I should define this both Controllers as servies and fo something like this:

```
<service id="my_controller" class="path/MyController" />

<service id="mycontroller_manager" class="path/GlobalController">
    <call method="setVariables">
         <argument type="???" id="???" />
    </call>
</service>
```

but I'm not quite sure about this and not quite sure how to fill the argument part or I should use Property Injection? Please help me to understand this better and improve my code :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are always going to apply the injection on the concrete class (which inherits it's abstract class). You cannot set defaults for all your abstract implementations.

Instead of applying multiple arguments to an ambiguous setArguments() method, you might want to implicitly have setters for each dependency (to each their own -- you can refactor this to a single method if you want).

```
<service id="my_controller" class="path/MyController"
    <call method="setUser">
         <argument type="service" id="security.context" />
    </call>
    <call method="setDoctrine">
         <argument type="service" id="doctrine.orm.entity_manager" />
    </call>
    <call method="setRepositoryName">
         <argument>Expense<argument>
    </call>
/>
```

No more init method.

```
class MyController extends GlobalController
{
}
```

Now we need to implement the setters to consume the dependencies.

```
class GlobalController extends BaseController
{
    /** properties */

    public function setEntityManager(\Doctrine\Orm\EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    }

    public function setUser(\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext $securityContext)
    {
        $this->user = $securityContext->getToken()->getUser();
    }

    public function setRepositoryName($repositoryName)
    {
        $this->repositoryName = $repositoryName;
    }
}
```